# Angularjs - Stopping selected quantity of Items being added to shopping cart basket if the quantity exceeds available stock

Tags: html, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is my total quantity function , the data is being populated by an external json file

```
             $scope.totalQuantity = function(){
                var total = 0;
                for(count=0;count<$scope.items.length;count++){
                    total += parseInt($scope.items[count].Quantity);
                }
                return total;
            };
```

And Here is where I'm doing my ng-repeat

```
    <tr  ng-repeat="item in items | filter: searchMaterial | limitTo: 10 "> 
                    <td class="desc-field">{{item.Material}}</td>
                    <td class="desc-field">{{item.Description}}</td>
                    <td class="qty-field" >{{item.ActiveQuantity}}</td>
                    <td class="qty-field">
                        <input type="number"  ng-model="item.Quantity" ng-maxlength="item.ActiveQuantity" />
                            <div class="qty-indication">
                                <img  ng-model="item.Quantity" ng-src="{{companyFileInfo.tickPath}}" ng-show="item.Quantity > 0 && item.Quantity <= item.ActiveQuantity " height="20px" width="20px" ng-click="removeItem(item)">
                                <img  ng-model="item.Quantity" ng-src="{{companyFileInfo.alertPath}}" ng-show="item.Quantity > item.ActiveQuantity" height="20px" width="20px" ng-click="removeItem(item)" >
                            </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Item total :

```
<h4>
     <strong> Total Items: {{totalQuantity()}}</strong>
</h4>
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: The problem is, that when I add an item over the available stock it is still being shown in the totalQuantity() at the bottom, when it is removed from the input filed, the totalQuantity() output shows as NaN.

Comment: create pluncker , it will help us to give you answer